# CHEF - Best Practice to pass data from an Orchestrator to Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, build-process, versioning

I just started using Chef about a month back so still quite green.  I am in the process of creating a cookbook that will deploy our applications which are in the form of RPMs.  I have it working just fine if I hard code the versions of the RPMs I want in an attribute.  However, there will be multiple versions of the same application RPM that come from different teams and from different branches in source control.

I need to feed in the specific version of the RPM I want dynamically from the build orchestrator.  I have thought about having it update a data bag with the version info for each build and use that to get the version I want but curious as to what others have done for similar situations?  Trying to avoid going down to wrong path from the beginning before I do this for 60ish applications.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I manage deploy time settings using environment attribute overrides:

```
echo '{"name":"app-2_0","override_attributes":{"app":{"version":"2.0"}}}' > demo.json
knife environment from file demo.json
```

All the servers associated with my application instance bootstrapped with this environment.

```
knife bootstrap server1 --environment app-2_0 ...
```

A secondary benefit of using environments is that you can also set cookbook versions constraints when loading new cookbooks. Makes sure that runtime behaviour doesn't change.

```
knife cookbook upload -E app-2_0 -o cookbooks --all --freeze --force
```

Comment: Thanks!  That sounds pretty straightforward.  Will give that a try and see how it goes.